# Output from python crawler

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, web-crawler, output

I have a python web using the scrapy framework. I am trying to get the output into two separate files - 
1) website to website data (i.e. website 1 links to website2)
&
2) keywords that match my list of keywords the crawler is looking for
I'm having trouble getting the output to work - I was able to get output for (1) without including the keyword component and I can see the webcrawler is working - the websites and appropriate keywords are listed in the cmd prompt. But, I cannot get them to save as separate csv files.

```
    def check_buzzwords(self, response):

        self.__class__.crawl_count += 1

        crawl_count = self.__class__.crawl_count

        wordlist = [
            "Keyword1",
            "Keyword2"
            ]

        url = response.url
        contenttype = response.headers.get("content-type", "").decode('utf-8').lower()
        data = response.body.decode('utf-8')

        for word in wordlist:
                substrings = find_all_substrings(data, word)
                for pos in substrings:
                        ok = False
                        if not ok:
                                self.__class__.words_found += 1
                                print(word + ";" + url + ";")
        return Item()
```

And to run the spider - this is the command, I'm using.

```
scrapy crawl examplespider -o examplesemanticlevel1.csv
```

Is it possible to have two separate output files from this model? And if not, any idea on how to combine the 2 files I need into 1?

```
The exact output that I need is as follows:
CSV File 1: 
starting website | Target website
website1       | website2
Website1       | Website2
Website2       | website3

CSV File 2: 
Keyword  | Webpage
Keyword1 | Webpage1
Keyword2 | Webpage1
Keyword2 | Webpage2
Keyword3 | Webpage3
```

I found some code online but I'm not sure how to incorporate it. Would something like this be usable?

```
 def spider_closed(self):
        with open("outputfile.csv","w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f,['Name','Year'])
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in self.itemlist:
                writer.writerow(data)
```

```
 def linkage_output_file (self, response):
        df = pandas.read_csv('websitesemanticlevel2.csv',
                             url = 'URL',
                             word = 'Keyword',
                             header=0,
                             names=['url','keyword'])
        df.to_csv('websitesemanticlevel2.csv')
```

Comment: You can write as many CSV files as you'd like, that should be no problem. Do you have a specific URL in mind or an example of the exact output you desire so that any solutions offered will be exactly what you want? Also, you set 'ok' to False and then check its truthiness unnecessarily.

Comment: @Dodge thanks for your suggestion! I went ahead and added examples to my question to give the exact format for the output I need. As for the "ok", would I just remove the "if not ok" statement to rectify that? Thanks!

Comment: Yes the code relating to that conditional is not useful as it stands (I don't think) so the assignment to `ok` and the `if` statement could both probably be removed.

Comment: Great, thank you for clarifying - I'll try it out without those and see if the results remain the same.

Comment: You should be able to do this with https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

I would manually add some code within the spider to write what you want to each csv, as the command line option is very limited from what I can tell

https://realpython.com/python-csv/ It's fairly easy, let me know if you have trouble

Comment: I just edited the main post with a portion of code - would something like that work?

Comment: the code I wrote did not work! Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Let me take a look. Any errors? I can't test it myself until I get home but I'll take a quick glance

Comment: No errors - but it also did not result in an output file!

Comment: unfortunately, that definitely did not work. I'm still trying to write the two separate csv files. Any thoughts?